# Serilog Enrichers don't log to console (.Net 6.0)

Tags: c#, .net, console, serilog

Using (.Net 6.0)
I am trying to output a few additional default information with all log
When I output to console I don't see the properties, however if I enable Json and output to file it all works, wondering if you have any clues?

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            //.WriteTo.File(new Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter(), "Logs/log-.txt", fileSizeLimitBytes: 5242880, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, shared: true)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithProcessId()
            .Enrich.WithProcessName()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Prop1", "ABC123")
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Prop2", "1.00")
            .Enrich.WithProperty("PID", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();


        builder.Host.UseSerilog(); 

        // Add services to the container.

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    
        app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
        {
            Log.Information("Hello....");
            return forecast;
        });

        try
        {
            app.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample is the default .Net 6.0 API (Web and Console -> App -> ASP.Net Core)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include these properties into the template of the `Console` sink.
The placeholders match by name; for the example given, use `{Prop1}, {Prop2} and {PID}`

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()    
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithProcessId()
    .Enrich.WithProcessName()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Prop1", "ABC123")
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Prop2", "1.00")
    .Enrich.WithProperty("PID", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id) // 9840
    .WriteTo.Console(
        outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3} {Message} {Prop1} {Prop2} {PID}{NewLine}{Exception}"        
    )
    .CreateLogger();
```

Output:

```
23:10:40 INF Hello.... ABC123 1.00 9840
```

Comment: Thanks for the help
For Json type
`.WriteTo.File(new Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter(), "Logs/log-.txt", `
Is there way to do the same but without adding a sub Properties:{} type

Comment: See also: https://nblumhardt.com/2021/06/customize-serilog-text-output/#-listing-only-hidden-properties-not-otherwise-present-in-the-message-or-template (_Serilog.Expressions_ formatting has some newer/more sophisticated options for including properties.)

Comment: One thing that's not been mentioned which might cover is that `{Properties}` in the `outputTemplate` will emit all properties that have not been used yet without referencing each one individually (see [the reference](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)). (Of course, Nick's comment is more than likely what you specifically are after though)

Comment: Hi @NicholasBlumhardt wondering if you can suggest somethihng for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73942087/file-sink-output-very-different-than-console-for-json